# Eigenvectors and Eigenvalues of Shift Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, circulant-matrices

$$S:\mathbb{C}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{C}^n, $$
 $$S(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)^T = (x_n,x_1,...,x_{n-1})^T.$$ 
How can the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of S be calculated?
I already have the standard matrix of S which is:
\begin{bmatrix} 
    0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 1\\
    1 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 1 & 0 & \dots & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 1 & \dots & 0 & 0\\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & \dots        & 1 & 0
    \end{bmatrix}

Comment: Note that $S^n-I = 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find its eigenvalues, note that $\lambda I - S$ is given by the following matrix:
\begin{eqnarray}
\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & -1 \\
-1 & \lambda & 0 &\cdots & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & \lambda & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0  & -1 &\cdots & 0 & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots &  \ddots& \vdots & \vdots  \\
0 & 0 & 0 &\cdots & -1 & \lambda
\end{pmatrix}
\tag{1}\label{1}
\end{eqnarray}
To find the determinant of (\ref{1}), you can use the cofactor procedure as follows. You eliminate the first row and the first column of this matrix and evaluate the determinant of the remaining matrix. Then, you keep the first row eliminated and proceed by eliminating the following columns. This will lead you to:
\begin{eqnarray}
\det(\lambda I - S)= \lambda \det\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\
-1 & \lambda & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & -1 & \lambda
\end{pmatrix}
+(-1)(-1)^{1+n}\det\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & \lambda & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & -1 & \lambda & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & -1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{eqnarray}
But these determinants are easy to calculate because both matrices are triangular, so you only have to multiply the main diagonal elements of each matrix. Thus:
$$\det(\lambda I - S) = \lambda^{n}+(-1)^{n}(-1)^{n-1} = \lambda^{n}-1$$
In other words, the eigenvalues of $S$ are the $n$ (complex) roots of $1$. Once you have the eigenvalues, the eigenvectors follow from direct calculations.

**Remark:** The $n$ factors are due the fact that I'm assuming $S$ is $n\times n$.

Comment: How are the matrices diagonal if you have non-zero elements outside of the main diagonal?

Comment: By 'diagonal' I meant 'triangular'. Sorry, I will edit it.

Comment: Okay, now almost everything makes sense. The characteristic polynomial would then be $\lambda^{n+1} + 1 = 0 \rightarrow \lambda^{n+1}=-1$. The solution I have to this question says the characteristic polynomial is $\lambda^n=1$. How is that equivalent?

Comment: You are completely right! I forgot to take into account that the matrices became $n-1\times n-1$ once I eliminated one row and one column. Now, it seems to be correct! Sorry my mistakes! I already edited it.

Comment: Thank you!! Now everything makes sense :)

Answer (score 2):

As [Rodrigo de Azevedo's edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3510533/revisions) to the question indicates, $\ S\ $ is a special case of a [circulant matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix):$$
S=\pmatrix{c_0&c_{n-1}&\dots&c_2&c_1\\
c_1&c_0& c_{n-1}&\dots&c_2\\
\vdots&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&\vdots\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\ddots&\vdots\\
c_{n-1}& c_{n-2}&\dots&c_1&c_0}\ ,
$$
where $\ c_1=1\ $ and $\ c_i=0\ $ for $\ i\ne1\ $ in this case.

The eigenvalues of $\ S\ $ are therefore the $\ n^\text{th}\ $ roots of unity, $\ w_j^{n-1}=e^{\frac{2\pi i j(n-1)}{n}}= w_{n-j}\ $, for $\ j=0,1,\dots, n-1\ $, where $\ w_j=e^{\frac{2\pi i j}{n}}\ $. An eigenvector $\ v_j\ $ corresponding to the eigenvalue $\ w_j\ $ is one whose $\ k^\text{th}\ $ entry is $\ w_j^{k-1}\ $:
$$
v_j=\pmatrix{
1& w_j&  w_j^2& \dots & w_j^{n-1}}^T\ .
$$
With $\ v_j\ $ thus defined, we have
\begin{align}
S v_j&= \pmatrix{ w_j^{n-1}&
1& w_j& \dots & w_j^{n-2}}^T\\
&=  w_j^{n-1}v_j\ .
\end{align}

Comment: What do you mean by minimal polynomial? And  "the eigenvalues of  S  are the  $n^{th}$  roots of unity,  $e^{2πij/n}$" is that a rule for any transformation? I don't understand where that is coming from.

Comment: The minimal polynomial of an $\ n\times n\ $ matrix $\ A\ $ is the polynomial $\ p(x)\ $ of smallest degree such that $\ p(A)=0_{n\times n}\ $. It always exists, and must be a factor of the characteristic polynomial $\ \det\left(x I_{n\times n}-A\right)\ $.  In the case of your transformation $\ S\ $, since the minimal polynomial has degree $\ n\ $, it must also be the characteristic polynomial.

Comment: The eigenvalues of $\ S\ $ are the $\ n^\text{th}\ $ roots of unity because those are the roots of its characteristic polynomial.

Comment: Following a hint from one of the edits to your question, I've now rewritten my answer to avoid all mention of minimal or characteristic polynomials.

Answer (score 0):

Since

$$||Sx|| = ||x||$$

we infer that $\lambda = 1$.

Then solving

$$(S-\lambda I)e = 0$$

we infer that $e=(1,1,...1)$

Comment: How do you conclude from the first equation that $\lambda=1$? The former is true of *any* rotation, for instance, but most don’t have $1$ as an eigenvalue.